# Mule Rest exception handling

Tags: mule

Mule Flows:

```
<jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
<component class="com.test.qb.rest.MapIIFContent"/>
<jersey:exception-mapper class="com.test.qb.exception.IIFExceptionMapper" />
</jersey:resources>
<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Audit Exception" >      
    <set-variable variableName="status" value="Failure" doc:name="Status"/>
    <flow-ref name="QB:audit" doc:name="audit"/>
    <http:response-builder status="500" contentType="application/json" doc:name="Status Code"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>
<logger message=" ===Reached here====" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> <!-- Line 10-->
```

Java Rest component:

Rest Component:

```
try{
    String s =null;
    s.toString();// throw nullpointer exception
} catch (IIFException e) {
    return Response.status(500).entity(e.getMessage()).type("Application/json").build();
}
return Response.ok(res).build();
```

When I run this, it goes to catch block in Java Rest component with error status as 500. 
But in Mule flows i am expecting flow should reach

> 'catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Audit Exception" >

block, but  it doesn't reach there, instead it reaches to line 10. How do I handle this?

Comment: Strange that you have both an `exception-mapper` and a `catch-exception-strategy`: isn't the `500` response created in `MapIIFContent`?  What happens if you remove `jersey:exception-mapper`: does the `catch-exception-strategy` works? If not, it means `jersey:resources` exceptions are intercepted by Jersey and never reach Mule.

Comment: @DavidDossot, after commenting jersey:exception-mapper, no changes, same flow continues and catch-exception-strategy doesn't work, i.e the problem, jersey exception doesn't reach mule. How to communicate to mule from jersey?

Answer (score 2):

I made rest component to throw checked custom exception instead of returning Rest Response status:

```
try{
    String s =null;
    s.toString();
} catch (IIFException e) {
    throw new IIFException(e.toString(),e.getCause());
}
return Response.ok(res).build();
```

And in my exception flows, made it as:

```
<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Audit Exception" >
    <expression-component doc:name="Create error response"><![CDATA[#[payload = "{\"status\":\"error\", \"message\":\"" + exception.cause.message + "\"}"]]]></expression-component>
    <http:response-builder status="500" contentType="application/json" doc:name="Status Code"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go, basically the component needs to throw a exception for the Mule exception strategy to kick in.